# $Scope Variable not update in HTML, although being updated constantly in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, counter

Code is Posted on codepen: 
http://codepen.io/karlsaks/pen/KzEyLR

Problem is I am building a counter that should show the numbers decreasing live as angular has 2 way binding , I am sure that they are updating in my controller side of the application (can be seen by accessing the console )

I am really out of options, any1 can help ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title>Counter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
<!--   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div id="inputBox">  
    <input id="userInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="clockdiv">
    <div>
      <span>{{days}}</span>
      <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>{{hours}}</span>
      <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>{{minutes}}</span>
      <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>{{seconds}}</span>
      <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>


    angular
        .module("myApp", [])
        .controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
            console.log("Controller loaded");
            var vm = this;
            $scope.getTimeRemaining = function(endtime) {
            $scope.t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
            $scope.s = Math.floor(($scope.t / 1000) % 60);
            $scope.m = Math.floor(($scope.t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
            $scope.h = Math.floor(($scope.t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
            $scope.d = Math.floor($scope.t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

            console.log("time remaining :" + $scope.d + " " + $scope.h + " " + $scope.m + " " + $scope.s);
            }

            $scope.initializeClock = function(endtime) {
                var updateClock = function() { 
                    $scope.getTimeRemaining(endtime);
                    $scope.days = $scope.d;
                    $scope.hours = $scope.h;
                    $scope.minutes = $scope.m;
                    $scope.seconds = $scope.s;
                    console.log("time remaining :" + $scope.days + " " + $scope.hours + " " + $scope.minutes + " " + $scope.seconds);
                    if ($scope.t <= 0 ){
                        clearInterval(timeinterval)
                    }   
                }

                updateClock();
                var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
            }


            $scope.initializeClock(new Date("May 12,2016 11:00:00"))



        }])
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you'll have to use angular specific `$interval` implementation, or you'll have to run `$scope.$apply` manually in each interval cycle, so that the $scope change can be digested.

My preferred method: Use `$interval` because it automatically uses `$scope.$apply`

EDIT: It seems like `$scope.$apply` is no longer available in angular version 1.5 (it was in 1.4). So I think using $interval is mandatory now

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed ! Works fine 
But found it weird, that the view wouldn't change autimatically, any explanation ?

Comment: Yes, every update of the $scope must be run inside an `$apply`. Normally, angular does that automatically for everything running inside the controller. BUT: With window.setInterval you are leaving the controller scope and change it to the window scope, which of course doesn't use $apply

Answer (score 0):

As devnull69 above answered u have to use $interval service, using setTimeout or setInterval make the process be unaware for AngularJS. So u have after them notify manually the angularJS usning `$scope.$apply()` or using their services $interval / $timeout that already do that behind the scenes.

So, in your case I would suggest the following implementation:

1 - Insert/Injeect the $interval service on the controller

```
.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope, $interval) {
```

2 - Alter the interval implementation (use $scope variable so u dont loose reference to your timeinterval variable.

```
            if ($scope.t <= 0 ){
                    $interval.cancel($scope.timeinterval)
                }   
            }

            updateClock();
            $scope.timeinterval = $interval(updateClock, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed ! Works fine 
But found it weird, that the view wouldn't change autimatically, any explanation ?